# using NLTK to find the related verbs to a specific noun

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Is there any way to find the related verbs to a specific noun by using NLTK. For example for the word "University" I'd like to have the verbs "study" and "graduate" as an output. I mainly need this feature for relation extraction among some given entities.

Answer (score -1):

<del>Given a corpus of documents, you can apply part of speech tagging to get verb roots, nouns and mapping of those nouns to those verb roots. From there you should be able to deduce the most common 'relations' an 'entity' expresses, although you may want to describe your relations as something that occurs between two different entity types, and harvest more relations than just noun/verb root.</del>

Just re-read this answer and there is definitely a better way to approach this, although not with NLTK. You should take a look at fasttext or another language vectorization library and then use euclidean distance or cosine similarity to find the words closest to University, and then filter by part of speech (verb in this case).